# .Net Core returning an int in HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to replicate the following ASP.Net code in .Net Core:

```
return Request.CreateResponse( HttpStatusCode.OK, 100 );
```

I have tried:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
    {
        sw.Write(100);
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {Content = new StreamContent(sw.BaseStream)};
    }
}
```

but it is not giving me the result I would like. I'm working with a legacy API which must read an integer from the response stream so I don't have the option of changing the design.

Below is the code which receives the response, the TryParse always fails, I need it to succeed. Unfortunately I have no way of debugging it:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();

    int value = 0;

    if (Int32.TryParse(result, out value))
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain "it is not giving me the result I would like". What happens or doesn't happen, are there errors?

Comment: I've added the code which receives the response in an edit.

Comment: Related post - [Convert from HttpResponseMessage to IActionResult in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51641641/465053)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

.net-core no longer returns `HttpResponseMessage`.

Controller has helper methods that allow you to return specific `IActionResult` results/responses..

like

```
public IActionResult MyControllerAction() {
    //...

    return Ok(100);
}
```

which will return a HTTP 200 response with `100` in the body of the response

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I needed.

Comment: How do send the custom message with `200 Custom Message`? i.e not in body

Comment: Prashant you can return a custom object that you can deserialise on client side