# Correct way to return HttpResponseMessage as IActionResult in .Net Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, coreclr

In .Net Core 2.2. I am creating a API Controller that routes the request to another Http endpoint based on payload.

```cs
  [Route("api/v1")]
  public class RoutesController : Controller
  {
      [HttpPost]
      [Route("routes")]
      public async Task<IActionResult> Routes([FromBody]JObject request)
      {
                 
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        // here based on request httpCLient will make `POST` or `GET` or `PUT` request
        // and returns `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`. Lets assume its making `GET` 
        // call

       Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = await
         httpClient.GetAsync(request["resource"]);
            
       /*  ??? what is the correct way to return response as `IActionResult`*/
      }        
  }
```

based on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641641/convert-from-httpresponsemessage-to-iactionresult-in-net-core) post i can do this

```
        return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode, response);
```

However i am not sure sending `HttpResponseMessage` as `ObjectResult` is correct way.

I also want to make sure content negotiation will work.

**Update 7/25/2022**
Updated the correct answer

Comment: You can't return an HttpResponseMessage object like in previous web api framework. Instead, you can create a custom IActionResult (like HttpResponseMessageResult) that will copy statuscode, headers and body to the httpContext.Response in the ActionResult's ExecuteResultAsync method

Comment: any example? The backend http api may return json result or stream. so the `HttpResponseMessage` will have that information as `HttpContent`

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: ye I posted my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/54187518/3862378

Comment: Related post - [Convert from HttpResponseMessage to IActionResult in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51641641/465053)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
public class HttpResponseMessageResult : IActionResult
{
    private readonly HttpResponseMessage _responseMessage;

    public HttpResponseMessageResult(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
    {
        _responseMessage = responseMessage; // could add throw if null
    }

    public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;


        if (_responseMessage == null)
        {
            var message = "Response message cannot be null";

            throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
        }

        using (_responseMessage)
        {
            response.StatusCode = (int)_responseMessage.StatusCode;

            var responseFeature = context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>();
            if (responseFeature != null)
            {
                responseFeature.ReasonPhrase = _responseMessage.ReasonPhrase;
            }

            var responseHeaders = _responseMessage.Headers;

            // Ignore the Transfer-Encoding header if it is just "chunked".
            // We let the host decide about whether the response should be chunked or not.
            if (responseHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked == true &&
                responseHeaders.TransferEncoding.Count == 1)
            {
                responseHeaders.TransferEncoding.Clear();
            }

            foreach (var header in responseHeaders)
            {
                response.Headers.Append(header.Key, header.Value.ToArray());
            }

            if (_responseMessage.Content != null)
            {
                var contentHeaders = _responseMessage.Content.Headers;

                // Copy the response content headers only after ensuring they are complete.
                // We ask for Content-Length first because HttpContent lazily computes this
                // and only afterwards writes the value into the content headers.
                var unused = contentHeaders.ContentLength;

                foreach (var header in contentHeaders)
                {
                    response.Headers.Append(header.Key, header.Value.ToArray());
                }

                await _responseMessage.Content.CopyToAsync(response.Body);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why you got a -1, this actually worked, with the exception of changing `Headers.Append` to `Headers.TryAdd` in my .net core 2.2 project

Comment: just wanted to add a comment that this worked in .Net core 3.1, not like the accepted answer.

Comment: It works with core 3.1! And if you add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;` it will resolve the `Headers.Append` extension method.

Comment: Is there a better way? Not to use that "unused" variable?

Comment: @Thor88 use discard identifier to get rid of unused variable warnings i.e. `var _ = contentHeaders.ContentLength;`

Comment: Namespaces needed: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

Comment: This supported all my scenario. Accepted answer has issues with loopback responses. Lets say you have 2 web API, (A) and (B). An endpoint in (A) calls (B) then (B) calls different endpoint but also in (A). (B) response back to (A). This works with this solution but not the accepted answer. Why would anyone do this, you may ask. Integration gateway for multiple applications. I just call integration gateway regardless where the data needs to come from, even if its coming from the caller. You dont need to make loopback integration different specially if integration source is defined at runtime.

Comment: This worked great, need to be careful with the using, since _responseMessage is being disposed in the ExecuteResultAsync method, don't place the argument being passed into the class constructor in a using or else it will fail.  Took an hour of troubleshooting to figure that out.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Works well with the content headers.

Comment: How do you cast HttpResponseMessageResult object to json data? How do you access the json data from HttpResponseMessageResult  object?

Comment: I am new to asp.net core, how to use this ?

Answer (score 31):

You can create a custom IActionResult that will wrap transfere logic.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Routes([FromBody]JObject request)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("");

    // Here we ask the framework to dispose the response object a the end of the user resquest
    this.HttpContext.Response.RegisterForDispose(response);

    return new HttpResponseMessageResult(response);
}

public class HttpResponseMessageResult : IActionResult
{
    private readonly HttpResponseMessage _responseMessage;

    public HttpResponseMessageResult(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
    {
        _responseMessage = responseMessage; // could add throw if null
    }

    public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)_responseMessage.StatusCode;

        foreach (var header in _responseMessage.Headers)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.TryAdd(header.Key, new StringValues(header.Value.ToArray()));
        }

        if(_responseMessage.Content != null)
        {
            using (var stream = await _responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(context.HttpContext.Response.Body);
                await context.HttpContext.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i was looking at https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/ResponseMessageResult.cs and https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/ApiController.cs at line no 523. Not sure thats going to work. Its basically returning `HttpReponseMessage` as `Response` property of ObjectResult. I will try your method as well

Comment: In webapishim they use custom formater (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/Formatters/HttpResponseMessageOutputFormatter.cs) that you probably need to register somewhere. This is a more complete implementation than mine.

Comment: Yep but as it's open sourced, you can get inspired by the part you need without every other compatibility layers.

Comment: i used your approach of creating IActionResult, however i used the code from https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/Formatters/HttpResponseMessageOutputFormatter.cs inside `ExecuteResultAsync`.. see my post below

Comment: Does not work for the following scenarios. Lets say you have 2 web API, (A) and (B). An endpoint in (A) calls (B) then (B) calls different endpoint but also in (A). (B) response back to (A). (A) cannot process response from (B)

Comment: Can you explain why ? Seem not related to this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Simply wrap the response in Ok() Action return type:

```
return Ok(response)
```

so your code would look something like:

```
[Route("api/v1")]
public class RoutesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("routes")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Routes([FromBody]JObject request)
    {

      var httpClient = new HttpClient();
   
      Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = await httpClient.GetAsync(request["resource"]);

      return Ok(response);
    }        
}
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: What if it is not 200 result?

Comment: @RomanBadiornyi sounds like a good use for an if statement after getting the response. Check out the link, you can return NotFound() BadRequest() (404 and 400 responses), and others. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-6.0#methods

Comment: @Michael G Then your answer is not correct?... Why would you always return OK?

Comment: @pooya13 You wouldn't.. I just showed simple example. If you have errors you can return BadRequest(errors) to send a 400 response. See link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core has the return object [RedirectResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.redirectresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to redirect the caller.

Comment: First, the link you provided implements `IHttpActionResult` not `IActionResult`. I know .net core has same objects. However redirect is used to redirect user to a particular url. My question is related to API not a Web Site. You dont redirect from API

Comment: I incorrectly remembered IHttpActionResult implementing IActionResult.  In that case, [RedirectResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.redirectresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is what you want.

Comment: How do you redirect a POST request? Or manage authenticated request without sending credentials to the user?

Comment: Does RedirectResult not support POST requests?  And I'm not sure what you mean in the second question.

Comment: Sometime the resource you want to forward need credential that you must not send to the request's user. In this case you can't send a redirect response but act as proxy server. Other use case, the target resource is in a network not reachable by the user.