# JSON data missing in the response body of a REST query

Tags: c#, json, rest, get

```
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get() //IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        WeatherForecast[] list = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        }).ToArray();
        HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
        msg.Content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return msg;
    }

}
```

using the GET query https://localhost:8675/weatherforecast

I'm getting the following response in the body:

```
{
    "version": {
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 1,
        "build": -1,
        "revision": -1,
        "majorRevision": -1,
        "minorRevision": -1
    },
    "content": {
        "headers": [{
                "Key": "Content-Type",
                "Value": ["application/json; charset=utf-8"]
            }
        ]
    },
    "statusCode": 200,
    "reasonPhrase": "OK",
    "headers": [],
    "trailingHeaders": [],
    "requestMessage": null,
    "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

**The data of Summaries array along with temperatures is not getting returned.
Could someone please inform how to send JSON data in the response body of a REST query?**

Comment: you could just do `return Json(list);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the `Object` with return type `IActionResult`

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get() //IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    var rng = new Random();
    WeatherForecast[] list = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    }).ToArray();
    //HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    //var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
    //msg.Content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return Ok(list);
}
```

Comment: you should skip the JsonConvert and just use `return OK(list);`.

Comment: @JasonC, yes you are right. you can just return the list directly. simple and easy.

Comment: Thank you Krishna and Jason for answering!
This change has resolved my issue. However, I wanted to ask if there's a way by which I can send the list using HttpResponseMessage or any other construct in which I can access each of the headers of an HTTP message.

Comment: @SumeetPannu, hope this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54136488/correct-way-to-return-httpresponsemessage-as-iactionresult-in-net-core-2-2 helps