# .NET Core API returning response from Web API not including cookies

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

I have a .NET Web API controller that contains the following login method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/account/login")]
//Web API Controller method
public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
        SignInStatus response = await this.SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
        if (response == SignInStatus.Success)
            return Ok();

        return BadRequest();
}
```

The method returns an `HttpResponseMessage` that contains a number of Headers including `Set-Cookie`.

What I need to do is to call this Web API controller from a controller written in .NET Core 3.1 and return the `HttpResponseMessage` unaltered. This what I currently have:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    //.NET Core Controller method
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(WebApiControllerURI, new JsonContent(model));
        return Ok(response);
    }
```

However, in the response from the .NET Core the `Set-Cookie` is not a header but is contained in the response body:

```
    {
      "Key": "Set-Cookie",
      "Value": [
        ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie=...."
      ]
    },
```

I get the same result when I try to return the `HttpResponseMessage` explicitly:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(serverUrl + LoginUri, new JsonContent(model));
        return response;
    }
```

How can I return the response from the Web API controller through the .NET Core controller and retain the headers in the `Headers` property?

Comment: Did you try to return `HttpResponseMessage` directly? 
Example: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/send-cookie-through-http-response-from-web-api/

Comment: @Serhii yes, I did. I've updated my question to show that I tried returning `HttpResponseMessage` explicitly.

Comment: What is the `HttpClient` Is it something you build? Could you show us the code? You could add those Header to the `HttpResponseMessage` When HTTPClient receive them.

Comment: @Alen.Toma It's the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class that I'm using.

Comment: Also, you could try to create a custom IActionResult: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54137811/8978576

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a cookie to your API request, then there are two ways:

### Method 1 : At startup

Used with static cookies.

```
// Method 1 - In Startup
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions()
    {
        Path = "/",
        Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
        IsEssential = true,
        HttpOnly = false,
        Secure = false,
    };
    context.Response.Cookies.Append("MyCookie", "TheValue", cookieOptions);

    await next();
});
```

### Method 2: In API

Used when you have a cookie with changing values:

```
[HttpPost("TestCookie")]
public async Task TestCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue)
{
    // Method 2 - Add to current context
    var context = HttpContext;
    var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions()
    {
        Path = "/",
        Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
        IsEssential = true,
        HttpOnly = false,
        Secure = false,
    };

    context.Response.Cookies.Append(cookieName, cookieValue, cookieOptions);
}
```

The context is always returned, even if you don't have a return statement. So you just have to set the cookie header in the context and it will automatically get returned.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `return Ok(response)` or just `return response` the framework takes the `HttpResponse` object and serializes it to json.

To proxy the response, take a look at this stack overflow question [Creating a proxy to another web api with Asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000362/creating-a-proxy-to-another-web-api-with-asp-net-core)

The code would be something like this:

```cs
/* Copied from the linked stack overflow answer.  Only part of the code since the linked question was about a full proxy. */
public static async Task CopyProxyHttpResponse(this HttpContext context, HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
        {
            if (responseMessage == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(responseMessage));
            }

            var response = context.Response;

            response.StatusCode = (int)responseMessage.StatusCode;
            foreach (var header in responseMessage.Headers)
            {
                response.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value.ToArray();
            }

            foreach (var header in responseMessage.Content.Headers)
            {
                response.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value.ToArray();
            }

            // SendAsync removes chunking from the response. This removes the header so it doesn't expect a chunked response.
            response.Headers.Remove("transfer-encoding");

            using (var responseStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                await responseStream.CopyToAsync(response.Body, _streamCopyBufferSize, context.RequestAborted);
            }
        }
```

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    //.NET Core Controller method
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(WebApiControllerURI, new JsonContent(model));
            await HttpContext.CopyProxyHttpResponse(response);
            return Ok();
    }
```

another option would be a library like [AspNetCore.Proxy](https://github.com/twitchax/AspNetCore.Proxy) depending on how much you need to proxy.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if AspNetCore.Proxy fits the bill.

Comment: Where would you get `_streamCopyBufferSize` from?

Comment: @DavidBrower not sure, that was copied directly from the referenced stack answer.