# How do I return a custom HTTP response in an ASP.NET Core Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET core MVC, how do I return a custom HTTP response, along with a custom HTTP code? I wish to be able to build the response myself, and preferably return it from a controller.

```
  public IActionResult Index()
    {
          // set custom HTTP response and return
    }
```

.... someone fetches Index, and I should be able to manually send a response alike below, where I can control every aspect of the response. I can even work with simply returning a string I build myself.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 12:28:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32)
Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Jul 2009 19:15:56 GMT
Content-Length: 88
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: Closed
```

How do I do this in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Core are you using? Are your deriving from `ControllerBase` or `Controller`?

Comment: You cannot manually set **all** headers in the response, such as `Content-Length` and `Connection: closed`, btw. And the host webserver will usually add its own `Server:` header (which you'll have no control over unless you specifically configure your outer web-server or reverse-proxy server). Besides, the whole point of using a framework like ASP.NET Core is to avoid having to mess-around with the low-level details of HTTP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practice to return errors in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732644/best-practice-to-return-errors-in-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690114/how-to-return-a-specific-status-code-and-no-contents-from-controller

Comment: @Mick It is not, that question simply asks how to return a status code. I was looking for a way of building my own responses manually and sending them to client.

Comment: @Toxcique well see the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641641/convert-from-httpresponsemessage-to-iactionresult-in-net-core)...

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently);
}
```

Another example if you wanted pass back a 400 status code and validation errors in the response body...

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var validationErrors = _repository.Validate()
    return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, validationErrors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised I was a bit tunnelvisioned, the answer is much simpler than I at first expected.

```
        public void Index()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 200;
        Response.StartAsync();

        return;
    }
```

This allows one to simply add data to a Response themselves and send them to the client. I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC.

Comment: "ASP.NET Core MVC" doesn't really exist in ASP.NET Core 3. Anyway, if you're using this approach then you probably should derive from `ControllerBase` instead of `Controller`.